# CSS: Topbar with horizontal scroll and dropdown buttons

Tags: html, css, overflow, navbar

I am trying to create a topbar that will be horizontally scrollable in small screens. The problem is that assigning 'overflow-x' to auto also sets 'overflow-y' to auto, so any dropdown buttons (or tooltips e.t.c.) in the bar, trigger the vertical scroll.

Is it possible to have only horizontal scroll, either with overflow or in any other way?

I have created a simple demo to demonstrate the problem. If you reduce the width of the browser the horizontal scrollbar will appear (as desired), but if you hover on top of the dropdown button the vertical scrollbar appears and the dropdown content gets 'trapped' inside the topbar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Title</title>
        
        <!-- CSS Classes -->
        <style>
            /* Topbar Classes */
            .topbar {
                display          : flex;
                justify-content  : space-between;
                position         : fixed;
                top              : 0;
                left             : 0;
                right            : 0;
                background-color : #dddddd;
                padding          : 0.5rem 2rem;
                overflow-x       : auto;
                white-space      : nowrap;
            }
            /* Dropdown Classes */
            .dropdown {
                position : relative;
                display  : inline-block;
            }
            .dropdown-content {
                display          : none;
                position         : absolute;
                background-color : white;
                min-width        : 100px;
                z-index          : 1;
            }
            .dropdown-content a {
                padding         : 4px;
                text-decoration : none;
                display         : block;
            }
            .dropdown-content a:hover {
                background-color : #f1f1f1
            }
            .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
                display : block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class="topbar">
            <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:12px">
                <div style="display:inline-block;padding:4px"><span>Navigation Top Bar Title</span></div>
                <div style="display:inline-block;padding:4px"><span>&gt;</span></div>
                <div style="display:inline-block;padding:4px"><span>App Information</span></div>
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline-block">
                <!-- Quick Search Input -->
                <div style="float:left;margin-right:3px"><input type="text" placeholder="Quick Search..."></div>
                <!-- Buttons -->
                <button type="button">Search</button>
                <button type="button">New</button>
                <button type="button">Save</button>
                <button type="button">Clear</button>
                <button type="button">Copy</button>
                <button type="button">Paste</button>
                <button type="button">Delete</button>
                <button type="button">Help</button>
                <!-- Dropdown Button -->
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button>Dropdown</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this code be helpful?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- CSS Classes -->
    <style>
        /* Topbar Classes */
        .topbar {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background-color: #dddddd;
            padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
            overflow-x: auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        /* Dropdown Classes */
        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: white;
            min-width: 100px;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            padding: 4px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #f1f1f1
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }

        /* phone size */

        .dropdown-btn {
            display: none;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            .topbar {
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }

            .dropdown-btn {
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .dropdown {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="topbar">
        <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:12px">
            <div style="display:inline-block;padding:4px"><span>Navigation Top Bar Title</span></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;padding:4px"><span>&gt;</span></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;padding:4px"><span>App Information</span></div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block">
            <!-- Quick Search Input -->
            <div style="float:left;margin-right:3px"><input type="text" placeholder="Quick Search..."></div>
            <!-- Buttons -->
            <button type="button">Search</button>
            <button type="button">New</button>
            <button type="button">Save</button>
            <button type="button">Clear</button>
            <button type="button">Copy</button>
            <button type="button">Paste</button>
            <button type="button">Delete</button>
            <button type="button">Help</button>

            <!-- Dropdown Button -->
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button>Dropdown</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- buttons link -->
            <button class="dropdown-btn" type="button" href="#">Link 1</button>
            <button class="dropdown-btn" type="button" href="#">Link 2</button>
            <button class="dropdown-btn" type="button" href="#">Link 3</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I basically use media queries to discriminate on the size of your browser. In this example I simply do it for phone size, but this can be applied to any size you want.

Comment: Thank you. The idea of setting the dropdown options as individual item in the bar could be a nice alternative.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- CSS Classes -->
    <style>
        /* Topbar Classes */
        .topbar {
            display          : flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content  : space-between;
            position         : fixed;
            top              : 0;
            left             : 0;
            right            : 0;
            background-color : #dddddd;
            padding          : 0.5rem 2rem;
            overflow-x       : auto;
            white-space      : nowrap;
        }
        /* Dropdown Classes */
        .dropdown {
            position : relative;
            display  : inline-block;
        }
        .dropdown-content {
            display          : none;
            position         : absolute;
            background-color : white;
            min-width        : 100px;
            z-index          : 1;
            left: -20px;
        }
        .dropdown-content a {
            padding         : 4px;
            text-decoration : none;
            display         : block;
        }
        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color : #f1f1f1
        }
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display : block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="topbar">
        <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:12px">
            <div style="display:inline-block;padding:4px"><span>Navigation Top Bar Title</span></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;padding:4px"><span>&gt;</span></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;padding:4px"><span>App Information</span></div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;">
            <!-- Quick Search Input -->
            <div style="float:left;margin-right:3px"><input type="text" placeholder="Quick Search..."></div>
            <!-- Buttons -->
            <button type="button">Search</button>
            <button type="button">New</button>
            <button type="button">Save</button>
            <button type="button">Clear</button>
            <button type="button">Copy</button>
            <button type="button">Paste</button>
            <button type="button">Delete</button>
            <button type="button">Help</button>
            <!-- Dropdown Button -->
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button>Dropdown</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your  answer, but the 'flex-wrap:wrap' property does what exactly is undesired. I would like for the contents of the bar to remain inline while the bar becomes scrollable horizontally, and while dropdown menus, toolips and any other expandable element remain visible outside the bar as normal. Thanks again.